# Contact Form 7, Wordpress, Date field

Tags: wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

My cf7 date field here:

```
<div class="form--date-field datepicker-input">
<label for="olean-date">Preferred Date</label>
[date olean-date]
</div>
```

Now datepicker triggers only when I click on calendar icon. How I can change it with adding class or id for whole div or input class? I need to trigger datepicker onlick on whole field, not only on icon. Image attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GPHe.png)

I tried to find class or id of calendar icon

Comment: This is answered in the docs.  https://contactform7.com/date-field/ scroll down to where it shows how to add class, then use jQuery or Javascript to trigger your datepicker